# Solving inequality with logarithm and ceiling function

Tags: inequality, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to proof the following inequality for a research.

$N(N+1) > 2^{\lceil \log_2 N \rceil}(\lceil \log_2 N \rceil+1)$ for $N \ge 8$

I know I have to proof that

$\frac{N(N+1)}{2^{\lceil \log_2 N \rceil}(\lceil \log_2 N \rceil+1)} > 1$

but I don't see any algebra manipulations that I could use. I already able to solve it using the upper bound of the ceil function. But, it's better if I can proof it without using upper bound.

Update:
I've managed to prove this using mathematical induction by using two cases: $N = 2^k$ and $N \ne 2^k$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $\lceil{\log_{2}N}\rceil=k $. Then we have the inequality $k-1 <\log_{2}N\leq k $ and since $N\geq8$, $k\geq 3$. Then the given inequality becomes

$2^{k}(k+1)<N(2k+2)<N(N+1) $

Comment: Why $N + 1 < 2\lceil \log_2 N \rceil + 2$? I tried to prove this as well, but I got the same problem like my original question.

Comment: First of all the inequality in your comment should have reversed sign. Next use the inequality $2^{k-1}<N $ which follows from the point where we define the number $k $. Then it is sufficient to prove the inequality $2k+1 <2^{k-1} $ which follows from calculus.

Comment: But, if $N = 8$, then $k = 3$. The inequality $2k + 1< 2^{k-1}$ doesn't hold because $7 > 4$.